# Treat separators as different tokens in Java

Tags: java

I'm having a hard time finding out how to read from a file and outputing separators such as ";" or ":" and so on as separate strings

This is what i have done so far:

```
int i = 0;

s = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("lab1.txt")));


while (s.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(s.next());
    i++;
```

The input file lab1.txt is:

```
cookies; and juice
```

The output:

```
cookies;
and
juice
```

What I want the output to be:

```
cookies
;
and
juice
```

Any idea how can i get that?

Thank you.

Comment: Will the separators always be a semi-colon, a colon, or a space?

Comment: No. I just gave some examples. I will also need characters such as "<" "." ">"  "+" "(" ")" etc.

Comment: split by space and punctuation marks ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use a delimiter for your `Scanner`.

It will use a **regular expression** to define your delimiter - see API [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

For instance (here replaced with a `StringReader` to reproduce):

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new StringReader("cookies; and juice")));
//              | whitespace
//              |  | or 
//              |  | | something followed by punctuation (non-capturing group)
//              |  | | 
s.useDelimiter("\\s|(?=\\p{Punct})");
while (s.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(s.next());
}
```

**Output**

```
cookies
;
and
juice
```

Comment: I was about to suggest `useDelimiter`, but you beat me to it. :P

Comment: Mena thank you for your further explanation and for the link. I have found what I was looking for there.

Comment: @Mena I have a problem when reading text without any separators such as `apple juice cookies whatever` . I get this error : `Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)` . Any idea what I should do? It only prints out the words on odd positions like: `apple cookies`

Comment: @Codemon with the example I provided and your space-separated input it doesn't throw that `NoSuchElementException`. Maybe some other part of your code? I'd ask a different question. **Edit** I mean, with your **new** input.

Comment: @Mena I just edited your example with this `s.useDelimiter("(?<=\\p{Punct})|(?=\\p{Punct})| ");` because otherwise the separators which were at the end of the line wouldn't have been output. I guess I just need to study the regex better.

Comment: @Codemon I think you mean the *beginning* of the line? You added a lookbehind group, which does indeed improve the solution. However I fail to see where the `Exception` you mentioned is thrown, even with your improvement.

Comment: @Mena I'm sorry, yes, I meant the beginning. After doing this `s.useDelimiter("(?<=\\s)|(?=\\s)|(?<=\\p{Punct})|(?=\\p{Punct})");` it prints fine but it's still giving me the error at the end. The error points at when I try to read another character by s.next() . Well, sorry for the trouble, I guess I'll have to figure out somehow :)

Comment: @Codemon I think I see your problem. You are invoking the `next()` method twice. That will work ok until it reaches the end, because it "nullifies" the condition `hasNext` in the second `next()` invocation.

Comment: @Mena Oh my gosh that was it. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Mena hello and sorry to bother you again. the reason i'm not asking a new question is because it would probably be a duplicate to this post. second is because it's quite simple: i can't figure out how to make the reading treat "==" as a separate token. not "=", but "==" . maybe you can help me still :D

Comment: @Codemon I recommend you ask a new question. It shouldn't be marked as duplicate as long as you post a clear input vs actual/desired output and the existing code as context.